# Push an element outside the screen when changing window width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have square div absolutely positioned on the left side of the screen. How can I constantly push it to the left after reaching some viewport width? The only idea I have is to add `resize` event listener through javascript and calculate `left` property of the element to be negative.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question. If you just want an element to stick to the left then your code is perfectly fine.

If your goal is to make is to make it stick only with a certain screen width, then I'd suggest you to look at [css media](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

As last, if you want this element to eventually "sink" in the left border, hence outside of the window, I'd suggest you to use a combination of css media and the [css calc function](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp).

Hope this is of any help!